# Way to use email as the authentication field?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-authentication

I am using django's inbuilt authentication system. Everything seems to be working fine. There are two fields that the user is requested to input at the time of signup: `username` and `email`. While logging in they are required to enter `username` and `password`.

I'd like to change this behavior so that username field is gone. I want to treat the email as the users username. So while signing in user will be required to put `email` / `password`

Is this possible while still using django's inbuilt auth system? I'm on django 1.7

**Update**

I had the need to add additional fields so I added the following to models.py

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    telephone_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    website_url = models.CharField(max_length=100)

User.profile = property(lambda u: UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])
```

Comment: This is specifically addressed in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model).

Comment: @DanielRoseman I went through the documentation but I have already made an extra model because I had the Need to add additional fields. See updated section of the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is directly in [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model), in short words you should subclass `AbstractBaseUser` or `AbstractUser` (in second case you can't totally remove username field), create your own user manager based on `BaseUserManager` or `UserManager` and customize built-in auth forms if you're using it (or any app that you're using is using it).

Comment: I went through the documentation but I have already made an extra model because I had the Need to add additional fields. See updated section of the question

Comment: @birdy you created an UserProfile model. You need to create a new User model and a new UserManager to make the field completely dissapear. Also, you'll have to implement custom views for registration and login

Comment: Creating extra model and overriding default User model isn't same thing. You can do both, but you must fix foreign key to user model in your profile model.

Comment: @GwynBleidD I'm using this app with an Angular front end. So everything is over rest API's I will change the front end..thats not an issue. If I subclass `AbstractBaseUser` would I still need the `UserProfile` model I created? Or when I subclass `AbstractBaseUser` I can add my custom fields in there as well...

Comment: You can move data from UserProfile into your new class or leave it this way, it's totally on you. If it's an live app, remember to put proper migrations into all of your apps that depends on user model, and also for app that will contain your new user model to move all data to new class. But it still can be not possible to migrate if any third party app depends on User class.

Answer (score 0):

This is not strictly cannon, but to avoid creating a new User class or Auth backend, I tend to let users log in with both username or email.

Anyways you'll want to ensure emails are unique as django does not check this by default.

You'll then have to override the default login view to support this. You can create something along the lines of:

```
class EmailUsernameLoginView(View):

    def post(self, request):
        next = request.POST.get('next', None)
        username = request.POST.get('username', None)
        password = request.POST.get('password', None)
        error = ''
        if username and password:
            try:
                usr = User.objects.get(email=username)
                username = usr.username
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                pass  # If the user doesn't exist, it's an username
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    return redirect(next)
                else:
                    error = 'Your account is not active'
            else:
                error = 'The username / email - password comb is wrong'
        else:
            error = 'Please provide a username / email and password' 
        ctx = {'error': error}  # Fill with needed feedback
        return render(request, ctx, 'registration/login.html')
```

This is just a draft and you should probably include a form to help with validation / cleaning

Comment: But this will still require users to enter username and email while signing up.

Comment: Of course. You'll have to override a lot the other way around.

Comment: You can also create some username (random or depending on email field) when saving user.